# PHPStorm does not start anymore

Tags: linux, phpstorm

I have phpstorm installed on ym Linux machine, and it worked fine before.

However, now it doesn't even start:

```
~/.../config/plugins $ phpstorm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
~/.../config/plugins $
```

Any idea what's causing this, or how can I get some more info from it?

I have version 8.0.3

Comment: It was related to jkd update. Try to kill all java & phpstorm processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it after asking for support, it was some problem with licence.

Basically it entered daemon mode and showed an alert box under all other widows, so it could not be seen. I stumbled upon it while logging off.

The box was a simple warning that license expires in 5 days. Not a big deal since I have a school license.

After confirming the dialog and adding new license key, it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand on it at all?  More information would be helpful to others with a similar problem.  If you accept your own answer, that will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Yep added the Info

Answer (score 0):

** Moved from multiple comments to one answer*

Thx @MightyPork. For me on windows 7, I found an alert for icloud setup (first time run) on background after seeing your answer. Once I closed the alert, I was able to start phpStorm.

**UPDATE 1:**

This time computer restarted from BSD (crash) & there was no alert. I end task MS OUTLOOK and tried, it worked

**UPDATE 2:**

Same issue as **update 1** but that didn't work this time.

This time it worked after force end task of 'slack' app. now I am wondering if this is something to do with memory (?)

So from now on, I'll be closing apps one by one until I can load ***PHPstorm***.

Once it starts, I can restart other apps fine.